# Is there a simpler way to write an if then else like the one below? Seems like there should be

Tags: vba

```
If [NEWHUD.X337] = "Y" and [NEWHUD.X339] <> "Y" and [NEWHUD.X338] <> "Y" Then
   [1218] = "Escrow Reserves collected for real estate taxes"
ElseIf [NEWHUD.X337] <> "Y" and [NEWHUD.X339] = "Y" and [NEWHUD.X338] <> "Y" Then
   [1218] = "Escrow Reserves collected for homeowners insurance"
ElseIf [NEWHUD.X337] <> "Y" and [NEWHUD.X339] <> "Y" and [NEWHUD.X338] = "Y" Then
   [1218] = "Escrow Reserves collected for flood insurance"
ElseIf [NEWHUD.X337] = "Y" and [NEWHUD.X339] = "Y" and [NEWHUD.X338] <> "Y" Then
   [1218] = "Escrow Reserves collected for real estate taxes and homeowners insurance"
ElseIf [NEWHUD.X337] <> "Y" and [NEWHUD.X339] = "Y" and [NEWHUD.X338] = "Y" Then
   [1218] = "Escrow Reserves collected for flood insurance and homeowners insurance"
ElseIf [NEWHUD.X337] = "Y" and [NEWHUD.X339] <> "Y" and [NEWHUD.X338] = "Y" Then
   [1218] = "Escrow Reserves collected for flood insurance and real estate taxes"
ElseIf [NEWHUD.X337] = "Y" and [NEWHUD.X339] = "Y" and [NEWHUD.X338] = "Y" Then
   [1218] = "Escrow Reserves collected for real estate taxes, flood insurance and homeowners insurance"
End if
```

Comment: Hi, welcome to SO. Please format your code.

Answer (score 0):

There is probably a simpler way but based on the pattern, you can try this:

```
Const prefixText As String = "Escrow Reserves collected for "

Dim outputColl As Collection
Set outputColl = New Collection
If [NEWHUD.X337] = "Y" Then outputColl.Add "real estate taxes"
If [NEWHUD.X338] = "Y" Then outputColl.Add "flood insurance"
If [NEWHUD.X339] = "Y" Then outputColl.Add "homeowners insurance"


Select Case outputColl.Count
    Case 1: [1218] = prefixText & outputColl(1)
    Case 2: [1218] = prefixText & outputColl(1) & " and " & outputColl(2)
    Case 3: [1218] = prefixText & outputColl(1) & ", " & outputColl(2) & " and " & outputColl(3)
End Select
```

Comment: I appreciate the feedback as I'm always trying to improve efficiency of menial tasks like this that I end up having to do a lot of in my line of work.  Thank you!

Comment: @griff67777 - If this answered your question please remember to accept it by clicking the tick at the left of the answer.

Comment: In general, if you notice that you are repeating something (whether it's string or a block of codes), it's good to consider to make it a const (or a separate sub/function if it's a block of codes) so that you can edit/reuse it easily.